# Why does my Visual Studio Online build keep failing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfsbuild

For some reason it keeps failing because it can't find some assemblies and I don't understand why it can't find them. It's an ASP.NET MVC application.

In the build definition my Source Settings is set to the src/ folder which contains the projects in my solution and the packages folder.

The build process template is TfvcTemplate.12.xaml which I'm pretty sure is one of the defaults.
Clean workspace: true
Label sources: true
Projects: My application's solution file
Clean build: true
Output location: SingleFolder

My errors are as follows

```
Controllers\CompanyController.cs (11): The type or namespace name 'OfficeOpenXml' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Global.asax.cs (7): The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Services\ExcelExportService.cs (8): The type or namespace name 'OfficeOpenXml' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (1697): Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Antlr3.Runtime". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (1697): Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "EPPlus". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (1697): Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Newtonsoft.Json". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (1697): Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Web.Optimization". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (1697): Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "WebGrease". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (1697): Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
```

I checked deeper into the logs and I can see that it's trying to find them but all it gets is "Considered blablablabla, but it didn't exist."

Why can't it find my nuget packages?

Comment: Does your build restore nuget packages in one of the steps?

Comment: I guess not. I don't see much in the log before it starts the ResolveAssemblyReferences step beyond creating directories.

Comment: That would be your problem then. No nuget packages => no dependent assemblies. Configure your build to restore nuget packages.

Comment: Well that's the thing. If I delete the packages folder locally and then attempt to build the solution NuGet restores all the packages no problem. It just appears that it doesn't happen on the build server. What are the specific steps I need to take to make sure the build is restoring the packages?

Comment: Are you building with msbuild locally and the packages are restored? any special flags you set for that? This was the guide I followed a while ago when I needed nuget restore on TFS https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build